# App relaunches when push notification is clicked in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I use a custom native Android library to render push notifications. When I click the push notification, the app relaunches. In other words, the app's onCreate method is called.

This library creates pending intent like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).addNextIntent(notificationIntent).getPendingIntent(notificationId, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

The code looks good to me. But could there be anything that can cause the app to relaunch?

In AndroidManifest.xml, I tried to set launchMode to singleInstance, singleTask, singleTop, but nothing changed the fact that the app relaunches when push notification is clicked.

Comment: When looking at the stack trace, here are a few method calls from top to bottom:
1. onCreate, MainActivity   
2. performCreate, Activity   
3. performCreate, Activity    
4. callActivityOnCreate, Instrumentation   
5. handleLaunchActivity, ActivityThread   
6. execute, LaunchActivityItem   
7. executeCallbacks, TransactionExecutor   
8. execute, TransactionExecutor   
9. handleMessage, ActivityThread   
10. dispatchMessage, Handler    
11. loop, Looper   
12. main, ActivityThread   
13. invoke, Method